# Select option filled with links from XML file , can i activate them on selecting?

Tags: php, xml

I made site with one select option where I can select any website I put in my PHP code and load their RSS feeds without going directly to the sites separately. But if I wanted to change links I must go directly in PHP code and change manually. Instead I want to change it in XML.

I made Select option drop down menu where I pulled data from XML file (contains only URL links). Now select option contain URL links on drop down.

Is it possible to make it work like that, to drop down menu, select URL and load RSS feed under my select box?

Comment: I would say yes. But whats your problem?

Comment: I got a little stuck and confused but i'll keep trying , if i can't really make it i'll post my code. 
Just wanted to know if is possible to load RSS feed by selecting site(loaded from xml file)from drop down menu.